# docker stop takes a really long time

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, sigkill

When I run docker stop on my Ubuntu 20.04 instance, it sometimes takes up to 20 minutes. Usually it takes about 10 seconds. Docker docs say that after grace period (10seconds), the docker daemon sends a SIGKILL. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/ So I don't understand why it would take 22 minutes +. Is the process doing something that will not allow to be SIGKILL'ed? Not sure how to debug this issue.

```
time sudo docker stop my_container
my_container

real    22m32.983s
user    0m0.140s
sys     0m0.050s

docker --version
Docker version 19.03.14, build 5eb3275d40
```